Comparison principle for order of convergence
Let $0<  x_n < y_n$ and $y_n \rightarrow 0$ with order 1.
More precisely
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}=C, \text{for } 0<C<1.
\end{align}
Can we say something about the order of convergence of the sequence $\{x_n\}$?
P.S. : It is to be noted that,
$ \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}< \frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n} $ is not true in general and hence the answer is not trivial(atleast to me).
Thanks in advance

Are you sure you don't want $y_{n+1}/y_n\to C$?

Even if that works for some sequence $(x_n)$, divide every second term by two to get a new sequence which is a counter-example.

@Jakobian Thanks. Corrected the typo

@LutzLehmann thanks for ur comment. I didn't fellow you completely. Could u please elaborate a bit.

For instance if $y_n=q^n$, $|q|<1$, then take the sequence $x_{2n}=q^{2n}$, $x_{2n+1}=q^{2n+1}/2$. The quotients now alternate between $q/2$ and $2q$, so their sequence has no limit.
